# calculate the angles of a triangle?

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

If we have a triangle $ABC$ and we only know three things:

-The angle $A$

-The length $AB$

-The length $AC$

Is it possible to calculate the other angles: $B$, $C$

---

All what I can think of is:

$$ \frac{sin(B)}{AC} = \frac{sin(C)}{AB} $$

But since there are two unkowns, I think that this is not possible. Does anybody here has a way to do that? Or is the answer simply no?

Comment: By the law of cosines you can find the length of BC, then from the law of sines you can get what you need.

Comment: Shouldn't this be tagged `trigonometry` and not `calculus`?

Comment: @Tomas: There's another method that uses neither the law of cosines nor the law of sines and gives a 'simpler' formula. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a = \angle BAC$ and $(b,c) = (|AB|,|AC|)$

**Method 1**

Let $D$ be on $AB$ such that $AB \perp CD$

Then $|AD| = c \cos(a)$

And $|CD| = c \sin(a)$

Thus $\angle ABC = \tan^{-1}(\frac{|CD|}{|AD|}) = \tan^{-1}(\frac{c\sin(a)}{b-c\cos(a)})$

**Method 2**

$|BC|^2 = b^2 + c^2 - 2 b c \cos(a)$

And $\frac{c}{\sin(\angle ABC)} = \frac{|BC|}{\sin(a)}$

Therefore $\angle ABC = \sin^{-1}\left(\frac{c\sin(a)}{\sqrt{b^2+c^2-2bc\cos(a)}}\right)$

**Question**

Why are the two formulae so different? Can you prove that they are equal without using this problem?